# $\int_0^1f(x)g(x) dx=\int_0^1f(x)dx \int_0^1g(x)dx $ implies $f$ constant

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function s.t.
>    $$\int_0^1f(x)g(x) dx=\int_0^1f(x)dx \int_0^1g(x)dx, $$ for all $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ continuous and not differentiable. Prove that $f$ is constant.

I've found that choosing $h(x)=f(x)-\int_0^1f(t)dt$ gives $$\int_0^1h(x)g(x)dx=0. $$ I don't know how to proceed. Can somebody give me some tips, please?

Comment: Proof by contradiction may be easier.

Comment: What happens if you plug in $g:= h$ ?

Comment: Are we sure about this formulation? Maybe you mean $g$ continuous but not per se differentiable?

Comment: if you plug g=h then integral of $h^2$ =0

Comment: And that means that $h(x)=0$

Comment: If my comment was not clear, how you know that you are able to set $g=h$? For instance $h$ might be differentiable?

Comment: We are sure. g is continuous and not differentiable... maybe we can't set g=h.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Max et al have noted, the special case $g=h$, *if valid*, gives $\int_0^1 h^2(x) dx=0$. But $h$ is real-valued, so $h^2(x)\ge 0$ with equality iff $h(x)=0$. For $h^2$ to integrate to $0$, the fact that $h$ is continuous implies $h$ is identically zero, so $f(x)=\int_0^1 f(t) dt$ is constant.

You seem insistent all we know about $f$ is that each non-differentiable continuous choice of $g$ obtains $\int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx=\int_0^1f(x)dx\int_0^1g(x)dx$. But it doesn't matter: we can choose such $g$ arbitrarily close to $h$, by adding to $h$ a non-differentiable continuous noise $\eta$ times an arbitrarily small coefficient, viz. $g=h+\epsilon\eta$. Then $$\int_0^1 h^2(x)dx=lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_0^1 h(x)(h(x)+\epsilon\eta(x))dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}0=0.$$

Comment: why is the last $lim 0$?

Comment: @Gaboru Because we're taking $g=h+\epsilon\eta$.

Comment: and why h(x)(h(x)+...)=0?